# I've been trying to implement a recyclerview for my activity but I keep getting NullPointerException in my onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to implement a recyclerview for my activity but I keep getting NullPointerException in my onBindViewHolder. I know this means i am passing a variable with null value to the onBindViewHolder, but i can't seem to find it!. This is my first time implementing a recyclerview  so if I'm doing anything wrong i would appreciate a concise explanation.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at cn.easyar.samples.helloarmultitargetmt.RVAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter.java:72)
                      at cn.easyar.samples.helloarmultitargetmt.RVAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter.java:20)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6279)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6312)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5258)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5521)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3254)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3767)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                      at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1218)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4975)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                    at
```

-->

My Adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>{


    Context context;
    List<Article_Data> articles = Collections.emptyList();
    public RVAdapter(List<Article_Data> articles, Context context){

        this.articles = articles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView article_data;
        ImageView articlePhoto;

        ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            article_data = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            articlePhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);}}

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
       ArticleViewHolder avh = new ArticleViewHolder(v);
        return avh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder articleViewHolder, int i) {
        articleViewHolder.personName.setText(articles.get(i).name);
        articleViewHolder.article_data.setText(articles.get(i).article);
        articleViewHolder.articlePhoto.setImageResource(articles.get(i).photoId);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void insert(int position, Article_Data data) {
        articles.add(position, data);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
    public void remove(Article_Data data) {
        int position = articles.indexOf(data);
        articles.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);}} -->
```

My layout file(row_layout.xml):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Description" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView> -->
```

My WelcomeActivity:

```
<!-- public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    private FusedLocationProviderApi mFusedLocationClient;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private List<Article_Data> articles;
    RecyclerView rv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




initializeData();
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.create();
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ayade_gov);
        builder.setTitle("Welcome to Cross River State!");
        builder.setMessage("Hello You!, A hearty welcome to Cross River State!, we the people will like to show you our culture...");
        builder.setNeutralButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           builder.setCancelable(true);

            }
        });
        builder.show();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
    private void initializeData() {
        articles = new ArrayList<>();
        //Uncomment data below to add info to cardview

        //  persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.lavery));
        // persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.lillie));
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        //rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        articles.add(new Article_Data("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.crs));

        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(articles, getApplication());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d("MainActuvuty", location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        //LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        //MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        //      .position(latLng)
        //    .title("I am here!");
        //   mMap.addMarker(options);
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        try {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                handleNewLocation(location);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id==R.id.nav_carnival){
            // Handle the camera action
//add articles
//articles.add(new Article_Data("","",R.drawable.ayade_gov));
            Sp.setDefaults("drawable", "R.drawable.ayade_gov" , getApplicationContext());
            Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(id==R.id.nav_gallery){
//add Gallery photos
            Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, FourInOneActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }else if(id==R.id.nav_calabar){
//articles relating to history
        }else if(id==R.id.nav_places){
//articles relating to places to be in calabar
        }else if(id==R.id.nav_share){

        }else if(id==R.id.nav_send){



        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
} -->
```

My Welcome Layout:

```
<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_welcome"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="cn.easyar.samples.helloarmultitargetmt.WelcomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_welcome">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        /></LinearLayout> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            article_data = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            articlePhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
```

All this variables are null because in your raw_layout it is not finding any view with associated ids. Please assign Views with Id

```
person_name
person_age
person_photo
```

in raw_layout

Answer (score 0):

Id in Holder different from id in XML:

```
R.id.person_name  AND title;
 R.id.person_age AND description;
 R.id.person_photo AND imageView
```

I wonder if it is the same xml! Or you did a copy-paste from somewhere!